# Pass integer parameter for Parameterized Jenkins Project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using a string parameter as below to pass on for a job to build.
[Parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1OBW.png)

It accepts only integer.
[Integer Parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIlX2.png)

Is there way to resolve this without using Groovy script?
Basically convert String to Integer
Parameters I have.
[Parameters list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoHOf.png)